# Tunneling ssh via a SOCKS5 Proxy on Windows

Tags: windows-7, ssh, proxy, git, socks-proxy

I'm using Windows 7 over my 'restricted' campus network.
I use **Heroku Toolbelt** to work with heroku projects, which inturn uses **git** and **ssh** on port **22**.
However, port 22 is blocked in my campus.  Can i use a **SOCKS proxy** like *Tor* to tunel my ssh and use it properly.
Thanks.
**PS**: I'm using Windows

Comment: Raise a complaint with the IT helpdesk. Blocking port 22 is completely unacceptable. Also, Tor isn't a SOCKS proxy.

Comment: Can you change the port from 22, as for example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4581442/165358)?

Comment: Well, i could solve the problem of ssh using Putty, by setting it a SOCKS Proxy on 127.0.0.1:9150.

Comment: @danielb, actually, Tor is a [SOCKS proxy](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en#thesolution)

Comment: @heavyd Just because it uses SOCKS to allow clients to connect doesn’t make it a SOCKS proxy. Tor is much more, which is not helping in this case.

Answer (score 9):

I have similar problem and I found this post: http://cms-sw.github.io/tutorial-proxy.html#infrastructure

While I could not find the version of netcat for windows that supports `-x` option, I found the alternative program [ncat](https://nmap.org/ncat/).

So,

1. Install [ncat](https://nmap.org/download.html#windows)
2. Edit the config file for ssh, usually found at `%HOME%\.ssh\config`:

   ```
   Host hostToYourRepo
       ProxyCommand ncat --proxy hostToYourProxy:1080 %h %p
   ```
3. Enjoy

PS. Options for ncat: https://nmap.org/book/ncat-man-options-summary.html

Answer (score 3):

use `ncat`, but you should set the proxy type like the following:

```
ProxyCommand ncat --proxy-type socks5 --proxy 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ProxyCommand "e:/sdk/git/mingw64/bin/connect.exe" -S 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p
```

you can try `connect.exe` if you have git installed

Answer (score 0):

For the strict use case of using Git, you can use http/https Git URIs. Git supports proxy settings including authentication.

I'm not sure if Heroku Toolbelt requires ssh though.